# AutoSuggestBox suggestions open in odd location

Tags: xaml, uwp

My application has a UserControl containing an AutoSuggestBox, which is nested inside of a ScrollViewer and is often not visible when the control first appears.

Often, the control appears with the suggestion list from the AutoSuggestBox visible and "floating" in the wrong place, that is, the list is not adjacent to the AutoSuggestBox (which is off screen). I can still click on the suggestions.

There are really two problems here, one being the weird location and the other being the fact that the suggestions shouldn't even be visible until the user clicks on the box.

Comment: Hi, can you provide the code, this can help us reproduce your problem. In addition, if you want to hide suggestions when the user clicks on the area outside the control, then `AutoSuggestBox.LightDismissOverlayMode ="On"` can help you

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to provide any code right now due to privacy rules surrounding my project. I'll try to come up with an isolated example and post it later.

Comment: The effect of enabling LightDismissOverlayMode is that the whole screen fades to light except for the suggestion list. Which is what you would expect if the list had been toggled by the user. So the problem here is that the list is being toggled open somehow without an user clicking on it.

Comment: `AutoSuggestBox`'s suggestion list will only be displayed when the data source is not empty. If you need it, you can manually set `AutoSuggestBox.ItemsSource = null` when `AutoSuggestBox` loses focus or other states